# Javascript fetch JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm trying to fetch a json-array via ajax.
my test.php returns:

```
[{"name":"James","age":24},{"name":"Peter","age":30}]
```

my Javascript looks like this:

```
var persons=new Array();
$.getJSON("../../api/test.php", function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index,value){
                    persons.push(new Person(value.name,value.age));
                });
    });
```

Problem is when I later call persons.length, I get Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
When I copy/paste the output of test.php from my browser into a local variable, everything works just fine:

```
var content=[{"name":"James","age":24},{"name":"Peter","age":30}];
for(var i=0; i<content.length; i++)
    persons.push(new Person(content[i].name,content[i].age));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"when I later call persons.length"_ - I'm guessing scope or async issue. Can you show us more context?

Comment: When are you trying to call `persons.length`?  `$.get` is asynchronous, so it may not be done yet.

Comment: See "[How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)" The difference is that `$.get()` is asynchronous, so `data` and all of the `Person`s created from it are available *later*, when the callback is called sometime after the surrounding code has continued to execute.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That may be relevant, however, it doesn't explain the error that is occurring. The error states that `persons` is undefined, but it is clearly defined in the code he provided.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you guys!! Thanks a lot !!!
I had a method showResults() that modified my html, solution was to call it inside de $.getJSON()
Async issues :D I feel so stupid right now xD

Comment: So, post your answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably an issue with scope.  If "var persons" is declared within a function then it is in the function's scope.  Double check where it is declared, and from where you are trying to access it.

For further reading see: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Edit:
I don't believe the asynchronous call $.getJSON would be the cause of the issue because persons.length would be 0 and persons would not be undefined.

```
var persons = new Array();
print persons.length; // ==> 0
```